# snap svg translate fragment

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

This is probably the best way, but I want to embed an external SVG and move it into position. I'm using the following code to load the external SVG image, but I can't seem to apply any transformation to the fragment.

```
var svg = new Snap('#svg');

Snap.load('logo.svg', function (fragment) {
    svg.append(fragment);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are really trying to transform, as you don't have any transform method in your snippet of code.

The normal route, is to append the fragment to a group element, and put the transform on that (as the svg element itself doesn't support transforms). So something like...

```
var svg = new Snap('#svg');
var g = svg.g();

Snap.load('logo.svg', function (fragment) {
    g.append(fragment);
    g.transform('t100,100');
});
```

Comment: svg.g() is not a function... for me.

Comment: Then you need to paste some code you are running. It sounds like you haven't set an svg element with an id of svg or something.